# Why is vscode committing changes as BuildTools from SpigotMC and how do I fix it?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

For some wierd reason BuildTools from SpigotMC is the contributor when I commit and push a change in my repository.

Do you have any idea how to fix it? The email it is using is unconfigured@null.spigotmc.org.

I am using these extensions for github integration:

- Git History
- Git Project Manager
- GitHub
- GitLens

**Screenshot:**
[Picture of BuildTools being the contributor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veud6.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the global user and email variables using:

`git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com`

and

`git config --global user.name "John Doe"`